# Can't install. Can't get past the License Agreement panel

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, installation

I've FTPd all Magento files to my server twice now.   Tried a good cross section of browsers - but I can't get past the first step of installation.  Just unticks itself and resets the page.  See quick screencast:

http://screencast.com/t/7FYsuPko

It is a bug?  Magento was happy with my server etc.
Can't see anyone else having this problem.

Can I bypass this step with a simple link?
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you attempted to debug what happens when you click on continue with something like firebug?

Comment: You can try to var_dump $agree and $step in app/code/core/Mage/Install/controllers/WizardController.php -> function beginPostAction .

Comment: Jonathan - thanks.. but can't see anything obvious with Firebug - no errors, or issues.

Comment: Michael - thank for reply.  Not sure what to do to try that... would you mind explaining a bit please?

Comment: Thanks Michael - I worked out what you meant.. and got past it.  But got stuck at the database step... same problem.  Obviously there's something fundamentally wrong going on here.  I'll try another server.  Cheers.